# Fullscreen Browser App without navbar

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, software-recommendation, fullscreen

I'm looking for a fullscreen browser app for iPad with no navbar, so the user can only navigate on the same page but not go anywhere else. Does anybody know an app for this? Or is it possible to do this in standard Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to disable the navigation bar on Safari for iOS. However, applications exist for iOS that may satisfy your requirement. You may want to search the internet for terms such as "kiosk browser ipad" or a similar query.

One of these applications is called [Amtel Secure Browser Kiosk](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amtel-secure-browser-kiosk/id570222997?mt=8). I have never personally used it, but it is free.

> Amtel provides a secure restricted browser & kiosk application for iOS
>   users. Browser policies can be configured such that only whitelisted
>   links are made available to the end users. The application is designed
>   to help IT departments at Healthcare organizations, Financial
>   institutions, Education sector, Libraries, Hi-tech, Fleet management
>   etc manage browser security on the iOS devices. The Administrator can
>   customize the settings to stop blacklisted sites on the devices or
>   allow only favorite sites on the browser. The kiosk mode is designed
>   to give the users the benefits of mobile device technology with fewer
>   distractions & security risks. The configuration of browser settings
>   is done at Amtel Mobile Device Management console - MDM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The keyword "kiosk" helped me a lot. There are many apps, i will now try to find the best one for my needs. 

At the moment, this one looks very good: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/surefox-kiosk-browser-lite/id670943898?mt=8

Answer (score -1):

Since i dont know much about technical terms so i will just post you the link check they have shown how to enable full screen in safari itself

http://blog.initlabs.com/post/81716286465/how-to-display-websites-in-fullscreen-mode-in-ios7

. or you can use apps like SFWB OR
FREE Full Screen Private Browsing for iPhone & iPad by SAVY SODA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found SFWB before i posted this question, but its "just" a fullscreen browser and does not allow you to go in kiosk mode.

Comment: you are welcome. And sorry for the SFWB i have never used this apps personally else i would have mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: @dking  The link is broken